# Django write permissions for development server

Tags: django, development-environment, file-permissions

I am trying to be able to upload / write files to a server for my Django 1.5 app using a local development server.

I have a model with a `FileField` in my app. When I try to save a new instance of that model (either using the admin page or the shell), I get a permissions error. Upon saving a new instance of my model, the app tries to upload a file to the server. Since I am running my app on a local development server, I can't write to the remote server's media directory.

The development server runs on my local machine through the `manage.py` script. The media folder where the file referenced in the `FileField` should be stored is located on a separate server. (the server where the production version is running).

The server is a dedicated machine running on `Ubuntu 12.04.2` and my machine local machine runs on `OsX Lion`.

The error I get upon saving a new model instance is:

```
OSError at /admin/.../add/
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www'
```

So the questions are:

Is there a way to be able to write files on the remote server from my local development server?

Or can I change the settings such that my local server creates local files for testing?

Comment: Show error and write what type of hosting/vps do you use. And why you want write something to remote server from dev?

Comment: The thing is how are you trying to write your files to the other machine. You are using a service on your remote server to recieve the files? Then it probably doesn't have access to the intended directory. You should add more detail into that critical bit.

Comment: In my app, I have a model with a FileField, the problem arises when trying to save a new instance of that model. When I try to save a new instance, I get the permissions error above. This happens for both the Django admin page or in the Django Shell. From your comments I learned that this is probably not be possible with Django. Do you think there is a workaround to make this work? Or is it generally not possible? thanks